# python gui AND/OR programm

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am using python GUI. So here's the deal https://learn.digilentinc.com/Documents/Digital/BT02_03_Basic_Logic_Truth_Table/AndOrTruthTable.svg

It should be like this. For example, if the user writes 1 in entry a and 0 in entry b and he chooses "and" radio button in label c should appear 0.

I tried something but it didn't work. Can anyone help me?

This is my code that doesn't work:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

a = Label(root,text = "enter number a")
b = Label(root,text =  "enter number b")
c = Label(root)


a.grid(row=0, sticky=E)

b.grid(row=1, sticky=E)

c.grid(row=3, sticky=E)
entry_a = Entry(root)
entry_b = Entry(root)

entry_a.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry_b.grid(row=1,column=1)

v = IntVar()


def ifvisnull(event):
    if entry_a == 1 and entry_b == 1:
        print(1)
    else:
        print(0)

def ifvisone(event):
        if entry_a == 0 and entry_b == 0:
            print(0)
        else:
            print(1)

button1 = Radiobutton(root, text="and", variable = v, value = True, command = ifvisnull())
button2 = Radiobutton(root, text="or", variable = v, value = False, command = ifvisone())

button1.grid(row=2,column=0)
button2.grid(row=2,column=1)








root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
"It doesn't work" is not a problem specification.

Comment: It is the same question as your previous [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65317923/python-gui-and-or-program).  If you have further information, reopen your previous one with additional information instead of creating new duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

my name is Vikas.
So there are a few problems i your code.

1. in all radiobutton , in the command option you had put parenthesis-()
   infront of the command which you have to remove
   ex: command=ifvisnull
2. then in all functions you have given event argument which you need not to
   until and unless you are binding the widget to an event.

   So,just remove event argument
3. Lastly , in each function to get the value of entry box you need to use
   entry.get() function/method.
   Directly writing entry_a will not give you the value
   And also this method will return in str type .